# Android coords of locationonsreen not matching actual screen

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera

I'm working on a camera app that has four circles on the center of the screen.

It looks like this;

[image]

My goal is to get only the images on the center circle parts.

My test tactics were like this;

1. implement a full screen camera with overlay(done, successful)
2. get the taken photo from 1, and display it on an ImageView(done, successful)
3. use the Canvas to draw a blue circle on the location of the overlay circles.(fail)

The blue circle gets drawn, but in some odd places.

here's my code.

```
        //x, y = x, y coord of the left-top circle of the overlay.
        //width = width of the left-top circle of the overlay.

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, width / 2, paint);


        imageView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

The circle is drawn, but in a really far place; almost below the bottom of the screen.

And the radius is almost twice as big as I expected.

I tried canvas.drawCircle(x + width/2, y + height/2, ...), but it doesn't seem to be the answer.

I used the below codes to get the x, y, width.

```
int [] loc = new int[2];
circle1.locationOnScreen(loc);
int x = loc[0];
int y = loc[1];
int width = circle1.getWidth();
```

Is something wrong with my codes? the x, y, width values are not 0, they have meaningful values. But it just not matches up with where the circles must be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

drawCircle locations are relative to your bitmap.  If the ImageView you're using isn't full screen, then your x and y will be wrong since they're in screen coordinates.  And by full screen I mean no status bar, not just filling the screen below it.

Comment: It has no actionbars. I disabled it using the theme value. The imageview is full screen. But, when scaling it down to 1/4, it gets a little bit smaller on the height, so I used imageView's fitxy scaling to fit the screen perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Gabe was right about it.

I was missing the whole concept that the coordinate of the screen itself and the coordinate of the Bitmap is different.

I solved it by using very simple math.

Bitmap total width : ? = Screen total width : x( x coord of circle1 )

? = Bitmap total width * x / Screen total width

same to the y, width and height.

So, using those values above, the code drawing a circle will look like this.

```
canvas.drawCircle(x + width/2, y + height/2 - statusBarHeight, width /4, paint);
```

The statusBarHeight is the height of the top status bar on the screen.

Since the bitmap does not contain a status bar since it's a taken photo, it should be subtracted from the y point of the circle.